# Как указать файл для логирования во время runtime?

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Я пользуюсь log4j и мне нужно указать файл для логирования во время runtime. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать. На крайний случай, хотя бы указать путь к файлу относительно запущенного jar-файла.

Answer (score 0):

Если логгируешь под SpringBoot то обычно есть такой фаил application.properties в папке resource там можно указать сам фаил и уровни логгирования

```
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource=ERROR
logging.level.o.a.catalina.core=ERROR
logging.level.ru.project=INFO

logging.file=file.log
```

Если путь для файла не указывать, то он его создает в корневой папке проекта